# Popover crashing on iPad (SpriteKit game)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Recently I discovered that it’s necessary to use Popover to display the ActivityViewController on iPad. I found this website as a main reference:

http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-share-things-with-a-uiactivityviewcontroller/

It’s perfectly explained, but I can’t make it work from my SpriteKit game. I double-checked with other examples and all seems to be in its place... but this crash on iPad anyways, without any meaningful message (on iPhone it works). I have no idea on what’s wrong. If somebody experienced the same, any clue will be very welcome!

```
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:@[twitterText] applicationActivities:nil];

UIViewController* viewController = self.view.window.rootViewController;

activityController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;

[viewController presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];

UIPopoverPresentationController *popController = [activityController popoverPresentationController];
popController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown;
popController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame),200,200);
```

Comment: Try setting the `sourceView` vs the `sourceRect` on the popover presentation controller. It would also help if you had the exception trace from the console.

Comment: Thank you Warren! The solution was including sourceView before sourceRect. I’ll set the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was adding

```
popController.sourceView = self.view;
```

before the `sourceRect`. Thanks and kudos to Warren Burton.